# how to show a website read only

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a website for managing POS terminals, where the status informations are shown (uptime, hardware status, etc.), and the users can do some actions (restart, software update, etc.) . I want to give access to this website to some third party, but I dont want them to be able to press any buttons, or any other input fields.

Is there a way to achieve this without modifying the source of the site? What I think about for example is to embedd the site in an iframe, and do some javascript magic.

The solution doesn't have to be super-secure, just to avoid accidental problems. (every necessary information is on the first page, so after the page loads, no navigation is necessary)

Comment: With jQuery -> `$('*').on('click', function() { return false; });`

Comment: You could Place a transparent DIV covering the whole Page and catching all events. Like it is used for Spinning Wheel wait screens.

Comment: Could you do a screen scrape and just render an image of what's been rendered?

Comment: @adeneo how do you leave the Page, if no more clicks are accepted? On a POS system, there is potentially no back Button. Or do I misunderstand the jquery statement?

Comment: The website is a management interface for POS systems, it is accessed via a normal browser remotely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery like the following

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    //disabling the input elements & buttons
    jQuery('input').attr('disabled','disabled');
    jQuery('button').attr('disabled','disabled');
    //disabling links through css
    jQuery('a').css('pointer-events','none');
    //disabling links through javascript
    jQuery('a').click(function(){return false;});

});
```

This answer is not a secure answer but it is a hack to help you through some situations.

or you can add the following code on the html:

```
<div style="position:fixed;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:1000000;background-color:transparent">&nbsp;</div>
```